# load external javascript jquery uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have a problem with loading external javascript. Sometimes i get an error like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SelectProjectView is not defined
```

and sometimes this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: HomeView is not defined
```

or

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SelectProjectView is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: HomeView is not defined
```

Here is the jsfiddle link : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3s3Lxvo/1/)

The strange thing is, that sometimes it's working. I don't know what to do.

Greetz.

Comment: I'm having this error on fiddle,
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined,
jquery js not included?

Comment: The calls are asynchronous, so if 1 JS file has a dependancy on another yet the other has not loaded yet you will see this error. You need to chain your dependant getScript calls in the callbacks. Your fiddle is largely useless as the paths are relative to your local server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i've found a solution:

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( "/path/to/script1.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/path/to/myscript2.js" ),
    $.getScript( "/path/to/myscript3.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    })
).done(function(){

    //place your code here, the scripts are all loaded

});
```

now it works as it should.